# Converting CSS menu from tab hover to tab click

Tags: html, css, tabs

I need your help,

How can the following code below be modified such that, as opposed to hovering over the tabs to switch them, that the user can click on the tabs to switch them instead?

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QA5Zp/

The CSS:

```
body{
    font : 12px/1.5 Helvetica, Arial serif;
}
.clearboth{
    clear:both;
}


#csstabs li{ padding:2px;}

#csstabs{ position:relative; width:500px; height:290px; }
#csstabs h3{ padding:5px; height:30px; text-align:center; cursor:hand; display:block;       font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; margin:0;
border-top:1px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #000;
border-right:1px solid #000;
}


.tabcontent{
    padding:10px 0 0 40px;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:40px;
    height:230px;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
}


#tab1 .tabcontent{
    z-index:2;
    background:#fff;
}
#tab1 h3{
    z-index:3;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    cursor:hand;
    background:#fff;
}


#tab2 .tabcontent{
    z-index:1; 
    opacity:0;
}
#tab2 h3{
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:180px;
    top:0;
    cursor:hand;
}

#csstabs:hover h3, #tabs:focus h3, #tabs:active h3{
    background:none;
    z-index:0;
    }

#csstabs:hover .tabcontent, #tabs:focus .tabcontent, #tabs:active .tabcontent{
    z-index:0;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition : opacity .75s ease-in;
    }

#tab1:hover h3,#tab1:focus h3,#tab1:active h3{z-index:4;background:#fff;}
#tab1:hover .tabcontent,#tab1:focus .tabcontent,#tab1:active .tabcontent{   z-index:3;  background:#fff; opacity:1; -webkit-transition : opacity 2s ease-in;}

#tab2:hover h3,#tab2:focus h3,#tab2:active h3{z-index:4;background:#fff;}
#tab2:hover .tabcontent,#tab2:focus .tabcontent,#tab2:active .tabcontent{   z-index:3;  background:#fff; opacity:1; -webkit-transition : opacity 2s ease-in;}
```

Comment: I think it just can be done with javascript, try jquerytools.org/documentation/tabs/index.html it's a light way UI tool library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS click events as long as you're willing to invest some time figuring out the proper targets and adding a few more tags. See [CSS Click Events](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/)

Comment: Most of this stuff is very new to me. Do you have a good example to work with?

Comment: There are examples on the page. You'll be using the "Transition Effect" on the `#tab1` and `#tab2` divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little bit of JQuery
http://jsfiddle.net/QA5Zp/1/

I have replaced the hovers in the css with a class named `active`
and with a little bit of JQuery you can make the tabs clickable.

JQuery

```
$('.tabbox').on('click', function(){
   $('.tabbox').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="tab1" class="tabbox active">
```

CSS

```
        #tab2.active .tabcontent, #tab2:focus .tabcontent, #tab2:active .tabcontent {
        z-index:3;
        background:#fff;
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transition : opacity 2s ease-in;
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work for me with your fiddle, I click on the second tab, and it didnt change.